# Ajax Post Back sending two arrays as parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an action method which have two string arrays as parameters, i am posting this action method with ajax post method, i am having one problem, On controller i got both arrays data same
but i am making both arrays with different data(one contains code other contains name)
below is my code

```
 public ActionResult SectionBook(string[] cs,string[] cname)
{
}

var CourseSection=new Array();
var CourseName=new Array();
 $('a p-button').live('click', function () {    
        var schoolCourseId = $(this).attr('id');
        CourseSection.push(schoolCourseId);
        CourseName.push($(this).html().split("(")[0]);        
    });


 $('#btnSubmit').live('click', function () {

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/MyController/SectionBook',
            //            dataType: 'json',
            data: $.toJSON(CourseSection, CourseName),
            success: function (result) {                
                window.location.href = '/MyController/SectionBooks'
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            async: false,
            cache: false
        });

});
```

i have debugged the JS code and both arrays are having different values here but in controller cs and cname contains same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the toJSON method only takes one parameter and ignores the rest. So by doing 
     $.toJSON(CourseSection, CourseName)
You are only creating a JSON object with the values of the first array passed in. 
If you wrap the 2 arrays in and object however like this

```
var CourseSection = new Array();
var CourseName = new Array();
CourseSection.push("cs1");
CourseSection.push("cs2");
CourseSection.push("cs3");

CourseName.push("cn1");
CourseName.push("cn2");
CourseName.push("cn3");

var newObj = {
 cn:CourseName,
 cs:CourseSection        
};
```

and then convert the newObj object to JSON with

```
JSON.stringify(newObj)
```

or

```
 $.toJSON(newObj)
```

You should be able to retrieve the values from both arrays in the controller using JavascriptSerializer

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

[ASP.NET MVC and jQuery Part 4 – Advanced Model Binding](http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.com/2010/05/aspnet-mvc-and-jquery-part-4-advanced.html)

Comment: Thanks,i tried this but it is showing internal error 500 and not hitting the controller as well

Answer (score 1):

Try without contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', you don't specify it anywhere at server side, so mvc tries to use defalut binding from request body in case of post. So just pass the js object as data parameter and jQuery will do a common post request with the neccessary object representation in the body of this request.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/MyController/SectionBook',
        data: {cs: CourseSection, cname: CourseName},
        success: function (result) {                
            window.location.href = '/MyController/SectionBooks'
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        },
        async: false,
        cache: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var data = { courseSection:CourseSection.toString(),courseName:CourseName.toString()};
            $.ajax({
                url:'/MyController/SectionBook',
                type:'GET',
                data:data,
                async:false,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    window.location.href = '/MyController/SectionBooks'

                }
            });
        }


In Controller
public ActionResult SectionBook(string courseSection,string courseName)
{

}
```

just confirm befor ajax call whether your array contains different value or not. and in json you should pass value in key pair and in controller you will get these value as comma separator.

Comment: yes before ajax call they are having different values but on this line $.toJson they have same values

Comment: Thanks,i tried this but it is showing internal error 500 and not hitting the controller as well –

Comment: Thanks for replying me i have edit my answer can you please try this one and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in `data:`$.toJSON(CourseSection, CourseName),`
it fills them with the first element check out the doc